# Can I do sql injection on this website

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, owasp

I am trying to fetch bulk data from a website database but could not succeed. Can somebody suggest if SQL injection is possible and how to do in this case.

[image]

Comment: Seems an evil intention ---> Is it safe to expose these details pertaining to Election Project? You do have a project path in the question, you know that?

Comment: Election project for Bihar elections, India ? Lol

Comment: @Sak - No, for the UP elections (check the application name)! I'll highlight this question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do SQL Injection to a website similar to the one you provided.

In the `where` clause it is expecting `ac_no`. I assume that this value is being passed from the browser as user input.  In that case you can pass `ac_no` value along with `or 1 = 1`. e.g   `where ac_no = 123 or 1 = 1`. It returns everything from the table `RollPdf1`.

For string comparison you can add  `"" = ""` to the `where` clause.

If you want to perform other `select` operations ( if you know other table names) then you can  append  `select` statements delmited by `;`.

**UNION operator** :

If you know the data types of the columns selected in the query then you can use `UNION` to get additional data from other tables.

e.g

```
  original query :  select  name, age, sex from table1 where id = 1

  sql injected query  :  select name, age, sex from table1 where id = 1 AND 1 = 2 UNION select username, id, password from userstable or someother table.
```

Comment: It is able to give one record a time only I want multiple record and I think there is application level validation is there for that.

Comment: From the  code which you shared, i don't think there is any application level validation to restrict it to only one record. Because if you see the `if` condition there, if there are more than 1 record then it is displayed in the grid otherwise probably just few readonly fields.

Comment: You can try appending `OR 1 = 1` to the `ac_no` value and try ..  Post the error you get after trying it.